# java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: null(in.java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier

Tags: java

My code compiles, but has a runtime error in my System.out.printf(%8d, %.1f...etc);

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentGPA
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data2.txt"));
        int studentNum,classNum,ctr;
        double avg,hours,grade,gradePts,hrsTot,gradePtsTot,GPA;        
        System.out.println("Fall 2013  Project 2  Due 9/19/13  by Tanner Triggs");
        System.out.println("STUDENT    CLASS      HOURS       GRADE       GRADE POINTS\r");

        hrsTot = 0;
        gradePtsTot = 0;
        ctr = 0;
        studentNum=in.nextInt();
        classNum=in.nextInt();
        hours=in.nextDouble();
        grade=in.nextDouble();

        while(studentNum!= -999)
        {  ctr++;
            gradePts = hours * grade;
            hrsTot+=hours;
            gradePtsTot+=gradePts;            
            System.out.printf("%8d       %.1d      %.1f       %5.2f         %.1f \r\n\n",studentNum,classNum,hours,grade,gradePts);
            studentNum=in.nextInt();
            classNum=in.nextInt();
            hours=in.nextDouble();
            grade=in.nextDouble();
            gradePts=in.nextDouble();
            GPA=1.0 * gradePtsTot / hrsTot;            
            System.out.printf("Totals:     %5.1f           %5.2f\r\n",hrsTot,gradePtsTot);           
            System.out.printf("\nSemester GPA: %.2f",GPA);


        }
    }
}
```

I believe all of my "f's" and "d's" are correct so I think it might be something else

Here is the data2:

```
87126534   1151   5.0    3.0
87126534   5100   3.0    2.0
87126534   4101   4.0    4.0
87126534   13198  2.0    2.0
87126534   2100   3.0    4.0
-999       0      0      0
```

Comment: Help us help you. Post full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot from `%.1d`, since the `%d` formatter is used for whole number values (integer, long, etc). So your formatter would just be `%1d`.

Comment: that was correct thank you. I forgot you couldn't use decimals with "d's"

Comment: @Tanner11 No problem. Don't forget to upvote and accept someone's answer, whichever one best answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You havent posted the stacktrace but here is an issue:

Remove the fractional part from the second format specifier to correspond with the integer value (`classNum`) supplied

```
System.out.printf
      ("%8d       %1d      %.1f       %5.2f         %.1f \r\n\n", 
          studentNum, classNum, hours, grade, gradePts);
```

Answer (score 1):

`%d` stands for `decimal`(base 10 integer), not `double`

`%.1d` doesn't make sense.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/Systemoutprintf073ffloatf.htm